# Enabling the citation feature on Stack Exchange postings

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Similar to [this discussion on math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8212/6876) and [this discussion on cs.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/2914), I would like to suggest to turn on the citation feature.

### Interface

Please note the "cite" link in the bottom right:

[image]

which gives:

[image]

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: Martin - for sites that use a lot of citations, they already have preferred ways to do this. Here on Security, I'm not sure I see a need at all.

Comment: I just wanted to cite an answer. Of course, I can created the Bibtex manually, but it would be nice to have it directly available. Espeically, as it does not bother people who don't need it.

Comment: Unlike some other sites, Sec.SE is not composed primarily of academics, but practitioners (both whitehat and blackhat). Citing posts is useful for people who are used to writing research papers.

Comment: I don't see any particular need either. However, is there much cost to enabling that? If not, I don't see a reason to actively oppose it.

Comment: Seems low impact to non-citation users, and I like the idea that somewhere, out there, someone has referenced a Sec.SE post of mine in some academic paper. No, wait, I meant to say "terrified" by the idea. I have no idea how to turn it on, though, or what any other potential impacts might be.

Comment: Isn't there a way to have this as a user preference ? (Or we could probably make a user-script of this)